# How to global search for substring in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode is currently set to global search only for exact whole words instead of substrings. For example, searching for 'redirect' will only search for that standalone word instead of other variables such as 'redirectTo', and searching for 'redirectTo' will not come up in the results for other variables such as 'redirectToLogin'. Is there a setting on VSCode to search for substrings?

Answer (score 1):

[image: search parameters]

See the middle option in the image - the Ab with the box on three sides of it - that toggles between whole word search and substring matches.  Make sure it is off for the substring matches.  It will have a (on Windows anyhow) a blue focus box around it if it is activated - match whole words only.